# Q_COREAPP_STARTUP_FUNCTION inside static library

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries, qcoreapplication

Qt has the `Q_COREAPP_STARTUP_FUNCTION` macro to register a function to be called as part of the `QCoreApplication` constructor. This works fine if used inside an application or a dynamically linked library. However, the function is not executed if used inside a static library.

As far as I understand, that macro creates a static class in whichs constructor the method is passed on to the Qt framework. But since that class isn't used anywhere, the linker simply excludes it when linking the final application.

The question here is: Is my assumption correct? And is there a way to tell  the compiler to not exclude such instance? The thing is I don't know if and how many are used, and thus it's impractical to reference them explicitly. Solutions for all compilers (msvc, gcc, clang) are required.

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct. the [docs][1] confirmed your assumption ***ten months after*** you posted your question: 

> This macro is not suitable for use in library code that is then statically linked

  [1]: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#Q_COREAPP_STARTUP_FUNCTION

Comment: Thanks. This does indeed confirm the behaviour and at least hint at the reason, but sadly does not explain how to work around it